# Flask-OpenID issues with proxy server

Tags: openid, flask

all - I'm having an issue trying to deploy a site that uses the Flask-OpenID extension. On localhost, I have no problems moving through the full login -> after login cycle - but on my production server, which is running an Nginx proxy in front of the Flask app (running with Gunicorn) I'm getting errors with the openid.realm and openid.return_to parameters of the response from any provider I connect to.

Basically, realm and return_to are pointing at my downstream Flask app instead of the proxy server. For example, for an intended "next" url of `http://www.foo.com/login/` the Flask-OpenID machinery is making the provider instead target `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/login/`, which is the localhost and port my Flask app is running on.

Is there any way to control this behavior and have Flask-OpenID correctly redirect through the proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your proxy server isnt passing on the HOST header, using nginx you can use `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in your location directive.

You may also want to look at setting the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) and X-Forwarded-Proto headers so you can read the actual client IP and protocol correctly. Werkzeug provides a [fixer](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix) to help with this, and there's an example detailed in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/#proxy-setups), `request.remote_addr` should then be what you expect.

Here's a more complete nginx location directive:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daz, I'll check it out tonight - in the meantime, I just hacked up Flask-OpenID and hardcoded the urls I needed instead of using request.host_url... it's pretty ugly, and this sounds a lot better. :)